# Vim + racer produce "Error "E117: Unknown function: racer#RacerComplete"

Tags: vim, rust

I want to have vim auto-completion for rust. So I installed racer globally and I got the source of rust by running `rustup component add rust-src`.

I have the plugin in `.vim/bundle/rust_racer/plugin/rust_racer.vim`, downloaded from the ftplugin folder from the `vim-racer` plugin repo.

And finally - in .vimrc I have:

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/rust_racer

" Set rust autocompletion tool "racer" ..
set hidden
let g:racer_cmd = "/home/petar/.cargo/bin/racer"
let $RUST_SRC_PATH="/home/petar/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src"
```

But when I open a rs file and try Ctrl+x + Ctrl+o to get the auto-completion - I get this error:

```
Error "E117: Unknown function: racer#RacerComplete
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install the whole plugin? Sounds like your missing an autoload file.

Comment: To future viewers [rust-racer is no longer actively developed](https://github.com/racer-rust/racer#disclaimer). Consider using rust-analyzer which is the now [officially](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/02/21/rust-analyzer-joins-rust-org.html) [supported](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/07/01/RLS-deprecation.html) LSP implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I had to download the vim file from the autoload folder of the repo into an autoload folder inside the plugin folder (in my case - .vim/bundle/rust_racer/autoload) - and now it it works.

(Don't know why they didn't write this in the `readme` ...)